# Ask Delta Method condition

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

In George Casella textbook theorem 5.5.24 Delta Method, it said let $Y_n$ to be a sequence of random variables that satisfies $\sqrt{n}(Y_n-\theta) \rightarrow n(0, \delta^2)$ in distribution. Then we will have a conclusion.

However, from another tutorial material, it said the condition is:  let $W_n$ to be a sequence of random variables (same as Casella). If   $W_n \sim AN(a, b_n)$, where $b_n \rightarrow 0$ and AN means asymptotically normal. In other words, it said $\frac{W_n-a}{\sqrt{b_n}}\sim N(0,1) $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

I can understand that here $W_n$ denotes $Y_n$, $a$ denotes $\theta$, $b_n$ denotes $\delta^2$. But the difference is that Casella has one more $\sqrt{n}$. It really confuses me A LOT. Can anyone help me?

Comment: No, $b_n$ denotes $\frac{\delta^2}{n}$. Otherwise, how $b_n \to 0$?

Comment: @NN2 That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @NN2 That makes sense. Thank you. Do you know what the relationship of this condition  $\sqrt{n}(Y_n-\theta) \rightarrow n(0, \delta^2)$ and CLT? I know in CLT, given a random sample $X_1,...,X_n$ with mean and variance, the sample mean is approximately normal. When I standardized sample mean, then I can see $\sqrt{n}$. It's very similar, but I am still confused.

Comment: This condition is the CLT. Remind that $N(0,\delta^2) = \delta N(0,1)$.

Comment: Yes, but "a sequence of random variables" shows up in delta method theorem. And $Y_n$ shows up in the condition itself. However, in CLT, that is a random sample $X_1,...,X_n$, and then the sample mean shows up.